# Threads and libraries

Tags: c++, ubuntu, pthreads

I get an undefined refference to pthread_create and pthread_join
I'm compiling my code with `g++ -lpthread threads.cpp`
I already checked for the libraries and `#include<pthread.h>` is the first line of my program.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `g++ -pthread ...`, no `l`.

Comment: and if I want it to take arguments from the keyboard(file names) like `f1.txt` and `f2.txt` will `./a.out f1.txt f2.txt` work?
My main looks like `int main(int argc,const char argv[])`

Comment: @Matt: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that a *totally different question*?!

Comment: it's based on the current topic but if it's hard to answer it here I'll make a new one